# Can't append one list to another in C#... trying to use AddRange

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, repository, addrange

Hi I'm trying to append 1 list to another. I've done it using `AddRange()` before but it doesn't seem to be working here... Here's the code:

```
IList<E> resultCollection = ((IRepository<E, C>)this).SelectAll(columnName, maxId - startId + 1, startId);                
IList<E> resultCollection2 = ((IRepository<E, C>)this).SelectAll(columnName, endId - minId + 1, minId);
resultCollection.ToList().AddRange(resultCollection2);
```

I did debugging to check the results, here's what I got: `resultCollection` has a count of 4 `resultCollection2` has a count of 6, and after adding the range, `resultCollection` still only has a count of 4, when it should have a count of 10.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you call `ToList()` you aren't wrapping the collection in a `List<T>` you're creating a new `List<T>` with the same items in it. So what you're effectively doing here is creating a new list, adding the items to it, and then throwing the list away.

You'd need to do something like:

```
List<E> merged = new List<E>();
merged.AddRange(resultCollection);
merged.AddRange(resultCollection2);
```

Alternatively, if you're using C# 3.0, simply use `Concat`, e.g.

```
resultCollection.Concat(resultCollection2); // and optionally .ToList()
```

Answer (score 4):

I would assume .ToList() is creating a new collection. Therefore your items are being added to a new collection that is immediately thrown away and the original remains untouched.

Comment: If I try making it get returned into a new list it says. "cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collection.Generic.List<E>'" so my guess is it's not returning anything?

Comment: The same mistake I made!  AddRange returns void.

Comment: Use the solution offered by Greg Beech. Also, if accepting go for him rather than me, i've only pointed out the problem, he's done that plus provided a solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

`resultCollection.ToList()` will return a new list.

Try:

```
List<E> list = resultCollection.ToList();
list.AddRange(resultCollection2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

<strike>IList newList = resultCollection.ToList().AddRange(resultCollection2);</strike>

```
List<E> newList = resultCollection.ToList();
newList.AddRange(resultCollection2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following:

```
List<E> list = resultCollection as List<E>;
if (list == null)
    list = new List<E>(resultCollection);
list.AddRange(resultCollection2);
```

Or:

```
// Edit: this one could be done with LINQ, but there's no reason to limit
//       yourself to .NET 3.5 when this is just as short.
List<E> list = new List<E>(resultCollection);
list.AddRange(resultCollection2);
```

Or:

```
List<E> list = new List<E>(resultCollection.Concat(resultCollection2));
```